# ASP.NET API app running in a Docker Container is blocking only POST and PUT requests

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I have the following set up for CORS in my .NET app:

```
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: rardkAllowOrigins,
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
```

When I'm hitting it from my app running on `localhost:4200`, only PUT and POST requests get blocked. GET and DELETE requests work fine.

Here's my `docker run` command:

`docker run -d --name=${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }} -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /root/cert:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`  (followed by a bunch of `-env` values passed in)

Comment: Do you have a full [mre] which can be run?

Comment: Not really, here's the repo https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/tree/dev

Comment: Yep, I've already seen that one and it is on no way minimal) Have you checked for differences in the requests (for example via developer console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason why your PUT and POST requests are getting blocked is that you are not allowing any header in your CORS policy. To fix this, you can try adding the **AllowAnyHeader()** method to your CORS policy, like this:

```
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: rardkAllowOrigins,
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader(); // Add this line
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the builder.Services, i've solved it using Web.config file
Using this configuration

```js
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: hmm okay, what does this look like in an appsettings.json setup though?

Comment: @muttley91 this looks like IIS config.

Comment: Ahh okay, yeah I'm not using IIS, I'm using Kestrel